# JScrollpane loses size after minimize

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

For some reason the jscrollpane somehow messes up the layout when the window is minimized and then restored.

Note that this is not happening if the text in the text area is not longer than the size of the text area (i.e. if it doesnt make a vertical scroll bar appear).

Can anyone see what's wrong with it?

My code below:

```
        super (new GridBagLayout());  

        textField = new JTextArea(20,80);
        textField.addKeyListener(null);



        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textField);

        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 80);
        textArea.setEditable(false);           
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        String[] dropValues = {"Format code","Add commas","Add quotes"};
        dropdown = new  JComboBox(dropValues);
        dropdown.setSelectedIndex(0);


        myButton = new JButton("Do it babe!!!");
        myButton.addActionListener(this);


        //Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

//        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(dropdown, c);



        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
//        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0; 
        add(scrollPane1, c);
        add(myButton, c);
        add(scrollPane, c);
```

When first launching the app
[image]

When text longer than textarea height
[image]

After restoring
[image]

Comment: please this code snipped already demonstrated described issue?, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0):

Use `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` with `weightx` and `weighty` properties for your `JScrollPane`'s. It will helps.