# JScrollPane shrink/collapse on window minimize

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a JScrollPane which contains a JTextArea.  When the window is minimized and then restored, the JScrollPane will then collapse on itself.  Note that this squish only happens if the text in the JTextArea exceeds the given width and/or height of the JTextArea (i.e., the horizontal or vertical scrollbars appear).

This question here: [JScrollpane loses size after minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773355/jscrollpane-loses-size-after-minimize) poses the same problem, but the issue is never addressed, other than to add weightx, weighty, and fill constraints to the JScrollPane, which I already had to begin with.

Below is a simplified example that demonstrates the problem.  How can I get the JScrollPane to sustain its size after the window is minimized and restored?

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class GUITest implements ActionListener {

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    SwingWorker<String, String> mySwingWorker = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GUITest tracer = new GUITest();
    }

    public GUITest() throws IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints mainPanelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        mainPanelConstraints.gridx = 0;
        mainPanelConstraints.gridy = 0;
        mainPanelConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        button.addActionListener(this);
        mainPanel.add(button, mainPanelConstraints);
        mainPanelConstraints.gridx = 0;
        mainPanelConstraints.gridy = 1;
        mainPanelConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainPanel.add(buildTextAreaPanel(), mainPanelConstraints);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel buildTextAreaPanel() {
        JPanel textAreaPanel = new JPanel();
        textAreaPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints textAreaPanelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        textAreaPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED), "TextArea"));
        textArea.setColumns(30);
        textArea.setRows(15);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane textAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        textAreaScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        textAreaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        textAreaPanelConstraints.gridx = 0;
        textAreaPanelConstraints.gridy = 0;
        textAreaPanelConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        textAreaPanelConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        textAreaPanelConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        textAreaPanel.add(textAreaScrollPane, textAreaPanelConstraints);
        return textAreaPanel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
            mySwingWorker = new MySwingWorker();
            mySwingWorker.execute();
        }
    }

    private class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<String, String> {
        public String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < textArea.getRows(); i++) {
                publish("text\n");
            }
            publish("more text\n");

            return "Done.";
        }
        public void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String msg : chunks) {
                textArea.append(msg);
            }
        }   
        public void done() {
            try {
                String msg = get();
                textArea.append("\n" + msg);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the weightx and weighty in both layouts.  In createAndShowGui, set mainPanelConstraints.weightx and mainPanelConstraints.weighty to 1 before adding the text area panel.

Comment: I can see that this produces the desired behavior, but I don't see why modifying the weight values of the container affects the size behavior of its child component.  Can you explain?

Comment: EDIT to above comment:  by "child component" I actually mean "grandchild component".  textAreaScrollPane which gives the errant behavior, resides within textAreaPanel, and textAreaPanel then resides within mainPanel.  So, how does changing the layout properties of mainPanel have a direct effect on textAreaScrollPane?

Comment: The weightx and weighty constraints determine whether a component expands to fill its parent.  It doesn't matter if the text area panel stretches to fill up mainPanel, unless mainPanel itself stretches to fill the window.

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout of the parent Container (the content pane) to FlowLayout

```
...
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
...
```

Comment: This solution seems to be working, but I don't understand why changing the layout of the JFrame's content pane affects the behavior of a component several layers beneath it in this case.  Can you explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the shrinkage problem in this particular code example by removing all GridBagLayouts and replacing them with BorderLayouts.  I have no idea why a JScrollPane reacts the way you discovered when using a GridBagLayout.

I felt real uncomfortable starting the Event Dispatch thread from the class constructor.  I moved the SwingUtilities invokeLater into the main method.

Anyway, here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class JScrollPaneTest implements ActionListener {

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    SwingWorker<String, String> mySwingWorker = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new JScrollPaneTest().createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public JScrollPaneTest() throws IOException {

    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScrollPane Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(buildTextAreaPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel buildTextAreaPanel() {
        JPanel textAreaPanel = new JPanel();
        textAreaPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textAreaPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED), "TextArea"));

        textArea.setColumns(30);
        textArea.setRows(15);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane textAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        textAreaPanel.add(textAreaScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return textAreaPanel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
            mySwingWorker = new MySwingWorker();
            mySwingWorker.execute();
        }
    }

    private class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<String, String> {
        public String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < textArea.getRows(); i++) {
                publish("text\n");
            }
            publish("more text\n");

            return "Done.";
        }

        public void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String msg : chunks) {
                textArea.append(msg);
            }
        }

        public void done() {
            try {
                String msg = get();
                textArea.append("\n" + msg);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about moving the EDT start to the main method.  After messing around with your version of the example, I found that it's only necessary to change the layout of mainPanel from GridBagLayout to BorderLayout.  textAreaPanel (wherein lies the infringing JScrollPane) can remain set as a GridBagLayout and the desired behavior is achieved.  This raises the same question that I had for the other two working answers to this problem:  Why does changing the layout configuration of a component affect the behavior of not its child component, but components that are multple layers below?

Comment: @FalconRunner11: It would be tough for anyone but an Oracle person maintaining Swing to answer your question.  I've found that I prevent a lot of problems by putting my Swing components in a main JPanel, and putting that JPanel in the JFrame.  Generally, to prevent a different group of problems, I create a new GridBagConstraints for every Swing component in a GridBagLayout.

Comment: I think VGR's response above offers a good enough explanation.  textAreaPanel should have the added weightx and weighty constraints when being added to mainPanel so as to handle whatever resizing may occur within itself.